# How to get the Quaternion from Matrix with python

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I found below code which is using for get the Quaternion values from Matrix.
Then, I would like to do the same work with it, but it's C++ programming language.
I can't find any similar python API to it.

```
geometry_msgs::msg::Pose  grasp_to_pose(gpd::GraspConfig & grasp)
{

  geometry_msgs::msg::Pose pose;
  tf2::Matrix3x3 orientation(
    grasp.approach.x, grasp.binormal.x, grasp.axis.x,
    grasp.approach.y, grasp.binormal.y, grasp.axis.y,
    grasp.approach.z, grasp.binormal.z, grasp.axis.z);

  tf2::Quaternion orientation_quat;
  orientation.getRotation(orientation_quat);
  orientation_quat.normalize();
  pose.orientation.x = orientation_quat.x();
  pose.orientation.y = orientation_quat.y();
  pose.orientation.z = orientation_quat.z();
  pose.orientation.w = orientation_quat.w();

  pose.position = grasp.top;

  return pose;
}
```

[Source](https://blog.csdn.net/flyfish1986/article/details/86245823)

Hope someone can help me to find out !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323980/how-to-get-the-quaternion-from-matrix-with-python/) by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2019-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-06-06**:
Check [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/324354/how-to-get-rotation-matrix-from-quaternion-in-python/). Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find the API you're looking for in here:

http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/tf/html/python/transformations.html

The function you need is called:

```
tf.transformations.quaternion_from_matrix(matrix)
```

---

Originally posted by [dasanche](https://answers.ros.org/users/20993/dasanche/) with karma: 83 on 2019-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2